# ASP.NET Core 1.1 - VS 2017 deploy console as webjob to azure together with the websites

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-webjobs, asp.net-core-1.1

In VS 2015, ASp.NET Core 1, I could deploy my CONSOLE (notice console not web job project) project as a web job directly to azure when publishing the website.

All I had to do was:

- create the path in the root of my website: `app_data\jobs\Triggered\DoSomeWork`
- add this in project.json:

  "publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "**/*.cshtml",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config",
    "app_data/jobs/***/.*"
     ]
   },

  "scripts": {
   "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
   "postpublish": [
    "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%",
    "dotnet publish ..\MyProject.DoSomeWork.WebJob\ -o %publish:OutputPath%\app_data\jobs\Triggered\DoSomeWork\"
    ]
  }

How can I achieve the same in VS2017? I've tried adding some building commands to copy the output of the console webjob to the app_data path, quite messed up. Doesn't work. I spent almost a day trying to figure out this.

I loved project.json!